# Create subgraph with nodes that descend from certain nodes removed

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx, graph-theory

I'd like to generate a subgraph with only the nodes that aren't ultimately successors of nodes with a particular attribute, `skip`.

Considering the following graph with node `b` having the `skip` attribute set to `True`, I'd like to generate the subgraph shown below it. In the subgraph, because `d` and `f` are ultimately successors of `b`, they along with `b` are not included.

[image: Full graph]
[image: Subgraph]

Using a brute-force approach, I can recursively find successors to `b` and remove them from a node list, then pass these to `networkx.DiGraph.subgraph()`, but I hope there is a more efficient way to do this, perhaps with one of the many algorithms provided by NetworkX (this feels like the sort of thing that would be included in a graph library):

```
def noskip_subgraph(g):
    # All nodes in g.
    nodes = set(g.nodes)

    for node, skip in g.nodes(data="skip"):
        if not skip:
            continue

        # Remove nodes and all descendants where `skip` is set to True.    
        nodes.remove(node)
        nodes.difference_update(nx.algorithms.dag.descendants(g, node))

    # Return subraph of g with `skip` nodes and their descendants removed.
    return g.subgraph(nodes)
```

For reference, here is the code used to generate the above graphs:

```
import networkx as nx
from networkx.drawing.nx_pydot import graphviz_layout
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

g1 = nx.DiGraph()
g1.add_node("b", skip=True)
g1.add_edge("a", "b")
g1.add_edge("a", "c")
g1.add_edge("b", "d")
g1.add_edge("c", "e")
g1.add_edge("d", "f")
g1.add_edge("e", "f")

layout = graphviz_layout(g1, prog="dot")

labels = dict(zip(g1.nodes, g1.nodes))
labels["b"] += " (skip=True)"

#nx.draw(g1, pos=layout, labels=labels)
#plt.savefig("graph1.png")

g2 = nx.DiGraph()
g2.add_edge("a", "c")
g2.add_edge("c", "e")

layout = graphviz_layout(g2, prog="dot")

#nx.draw(g2, pos=layout, with_labels=True)
#plt.savefig("graph2.png")

def noskip_subgraph(g):
    nodes = set(g.nodes)

    for node, skip in g.nodes(data="skip"):
        if not skip:
            continue

        # Remove nodes and all descendants where `skip` is set to True.    
        nodes.remove(node)
        nodes.difference_update(nx.algorithms.dag.descendants(g, node))

    return g.subgraph(nodes)

g3 = noskip_subgraph(g1)

layout = graphviz_layout(g2, prog="dot")

nx.draw(g3, pos=layout, with_labels=True)
plt.savefig("graph3.png")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of sets to make this a little more efficient.

```
def noskip_subgraph(g):
    nodes_to_rm = set()
    for node, skip in g.nodes(data="skip"):
        if not skip:
            continue

        nodes_to_rm.update(nx.descendants(g, node))

    return g.subgraph(g.nodes - nodes_to_rm)
```

Comment: Thanks, looks good! I still hope (but hope is fading) that there's a built-in algorithm to do what I need here in the most efficient way possible though. For example, descendants don't need to be recomputed for nodes that were already part of a previously computed descendant set. In this case the fourth line can be changed to `if skip or node in nodes_to_rm` but ideally this along with other improvements would be wrapped up in some existing `nx` algorithm...